# Magento Get Attribute values Collection by filter

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I am using Magento 1.9.3.6 version.
I have an attribute called `brand`.
I want to get `brand` attribute's values collection by filter in order to show it in input text box as autocomplete suggestions.

[image: brand attribute]

I have tried the following code:

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel("eav/entity_attribute")->getIdByCode("catalog_product","brand");
$attribute = Mage::getModel("catalog/resource_eav_attribute")->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

I get this output in autocomplete input box:

[image: auto complete]

When I tried like this,

```
 $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions()->addAttributeToFilter("value", "brand");
```

it shows error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() on array in .../CustomController.php on line 52

How to get attribute values as array filter by brand values.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'brand');
if($attribute && $attribute->getId()) {
    $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute($attribute)
        ->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach ($options as $option) {
       print_r($option);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting the attribute values in array. I want to filter in the array  values.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , it will get all option of the particular attribute

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
$optionArray = array();
foreach ($allOptions as $key => $value) {
    $optionArray[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
}
print_r($optionArray);
```

Comment: I am getting the attribute values in array. I want to filter in the array  values.

Comment: I don't know any way to filter attribute option label, but you can add a if condition to check matching label before adding option to the $optionArray in above code foreach loop